# Determine responsive heights of children in a vertical LinearLayout inside of a ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, responsive, percentage

I want to give responsive height to children in a vertical Linearlayout for example(some view height must be 25% of the screen height) I know this is simple if I use weight but the problem is that I have the LinearLayout inside a ScrollView this means I dont know the exact height of the LinearLayout so weight doesn't work here.can anyone give me a way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
scrollView.setFillViewport(true)
```

This way, the linear layout inside occupies the full height.